# Reverse an arbitrary dimension in an ndarray

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I'm working with an n-dimensional array, and I'd like a way to reverse a numbered dimension. So rather than

```
rev = a[:,:,::-1]
```

I'd like to be able to write

```
rev = a.reverse(dimension=2)
```

or something similar. I can't seem to find examples that don't rely on the former syntax.

Comment: If you know the syntax you need, why not roll that into your own `rev` function?

Comment: I'd be fine with that, but I want the function to take an integer (the dimension to reverse) and return the array reversed along that dimension. I don't know how to translate (for example) `1` into `[:,::-1,:]` and `0` into `[::-1,:,:]` for an arbitrary number of dimensions.

Comment: Numpy's `__getitem__` takes a `tuple` of `slice`s so you can do `a[tuple(slice(None, None, -1) if idx == dimension else slice(None) for idx in range(a.ndim))]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone coming across this in the future:

Numpy 1.12+ has the function [`np.flip(array, dimension)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html), which does exactly as requested. Even better, it returns a view of the data rather than a copy, and so it happens in constant time.

Answer (score 11):

If you browse the numpy (python) source code you'll find a trick they use to write functions that operate on a particular axis is to use `np.swapaxes` to put the target axis in the `axis = 0` position. Then they write code that operates on the `0-axis`, and then they use `np.swapaxes` again to put the `0-axis` back in its original position.

You can do that here like so:

```
import numpy as np
def rev(a, axis = -1):
    a = np.asarray(a).swapaxes(axis, 0)
    a = a[::-1,...]
    a = a.swapaxes(0, axis)
    return a

a = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)

print(rev(a, axis = 2))
```

yields

```
[[[ 3  2  1  0]
  [ 7  6  5  4]
  [11 10  9  8]]

 [[15 14 13 12]
  [19 18 17 16]
  [23 22 21 20]]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Turns out this can be done with `slice`, for which `:` is shorthand in some contexts. The trick is to build the index object as a tuple of slices:

```
import numpy as np

def reverse(a, axis=0): 
    idx = [slice(None)]*len(a.shape)
    idx[axis] = slice(None, None, -1)
    return a[idx]

a = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
print reverse(a, axis=2)
```

With `Ellipsis` this can be collapsed into a one-liner:

```
a[[slice(None)]*axis + [slice(None, None, -1)] + [Ellipsis]]
```