# How the `along a specific axis` operation implemented?

Tags: python, numpy

I can `sum` all the elements along a specific axis, using `numpy.sum`, that is

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
>>> numpy.sum(a, 1)
array([3, 7])
```

That is `sum along row`, which add elements of each column one by one.

If there are only 2 or 3 axes, I could implement it using `if...elif` or `swith...case` in C/C++, but what if there are 100 axes? How to implement it?

Comment: What do you want to implement?

Comment: numpy arrays are just one-dimensional C arrays under the hood, so stepping along a single axis is implemented by jumping through the C array in strides. So you would have to calculate the stride corresponding to the axis, and then step through the array while calculating the sum.

Comment: Also, from Python you can use `np.rollaxis` to move the nth axis to the beginning and implement it only for the first dimension.

Comment: @Evert, you answered my question, ;-)

Comment: That was an accident, I swear. If you'd like to know a bit more, you could read chapter 15 (no real need to read all the previous ones) of the [guide to numpy](www.tramy.us/numpybook.pdf‎), which starts of with a section on numpy array iterations as it's done in C.

Comment: @Evert, thanks, I'll dig in.

Comment: @Evert you could add your comment as an answer...

Comment: As @jorgeca already mentioned, `numpy.swapaxes` is usually how this is done.  For example, have a look at unutbu's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13240248/325565

Comment: Just posted my two comments as an answer, to make it easier for other people landing on this page after a search, to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy arrays are just one-dimensional C arrays under the hood, so stepping along a single axis is implemented by jumping through the C array in strides, the size of the stride depending on which dimension you're iterating over (smallest strides for the fastest dimension, which in Python/C would be the last dimension).

So you would have to calculate the stride corresponding to the axis, and then step through the array while calculating the sum. For each sum, you start at an offset in the array (the first would be 0), that increases with yet another step size.

If you'd like to know a bit more, you could read chapter 15 (no real need to read all the previous ones) of the [guide to numpy](http://www.tramy.us/), which starts with a section on numpy array iterations as it's done in C.

Comment: Upvoted, furthermore, I found out that most of core methods in `numpy` and `scipy` are actually implemented using `C/C++`, such as `convolve` and `correlate`, Why is that? Performance concern? What if implementing them using PURE `python` code?

Comment: @Alcott: that is the whole point of numpy and scipy: performance. Only when you go routes like PyPy you might get the same speed as native C routines, but often only for some specific operations (I haven't tried to implement various of the more fancy numpy/scipy routines in pure Python with PyPy and then compare). Using pure Python and normal CPython will often get you slowdowns of factors of 100s.

Comment: @alcott: also, code reuse. There is lots of code out there, optimized for speed, mostly in C or FORTRAN. Numpy and scipy interface with some of these libraries (or at least can), such as the standard linear algebra (BLAS, LAPACK) routines. Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, they just provide a Pythonic interface to something that's been optimized (and debugged!) and proven over the years.